# Lookupset with a stored procedure syntax

Tags: reporting-services

I have a stored procedure that requires 2 parameters be passed to it.   I don't think this can be done with lookupset, can it?

Comment: by this, I mean utilizing the lookupset command on it.   The goal is to execute a join command on a field the stored procedure returns.  But I'm not sure how my syntax would go.

Comment: Join(Lookupset(True, True, Fieldname, DatasourceName), ", ")

Answer (score 1):

```
Join(Lookupset(True, True, Fieldname, DatasourceName), ", ")
```